# Cannot find module 'tedious' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am getting the error in the title pointing to the line `const Request = require('tedious').Request`. What's strange to me is that there is no error on the line before it, which also uses `tedious`.

**What I've tried:**

I went into package.json and noticed that the tedious dependency was only in the dependencies section but not devDependencies, so I added it there. I tried this because I am currently using the dev env and using `npm run dev` to run the server. This didn't work though.

I also did `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P` and selected the `Typescript: Restart TS Server` option, but this didn't work.

**server.ts**

```
/**
 * Setup express server.
 */

import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import path from 'path';
import helmet from 'helmet';
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import logger from 'jet-logger';

import 'express-async-errors';

import BaseRouter from '@src/routes/api';
import Paths from '@src/routes/constants/Paths';

import EnvVars from '@src/constants/EnvVars';
import HttpStatusCodes from '@src/constants/HttpStatusCodes';

import { NodeEnvs } from '@src/constants/misc';
import { RouteError } from '@src/other/classes';

// AV
const Connection = require('tedious').Connection
const Request = require('tedious').Request //ERROR POINTS HERE


// **** Variables **** //

const app = express();

// Connect to SQL Server    
const config = {
  server: 'localhost',
  authentication: {
    type: 'default',
    options: {
      userName: 'your_username', // update me
      password: 'your_password' // update me
    }
  }
}

const connection = new Connection(config)

connection.on('connect', (err: any) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    executeStatement()
  }
})

function executeStatement () {
  var request = new Request("select 123, 'hello world'", (err: any, rowCount: any) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      console.log(`${rowCount} rows`)
    }
    connection.close()
  })

  request.on('row', (columns: any) => {
    columns.forEach((column: any) => {
      if (column.value === null) {
        console.log('NULL')
      } else {
        console.log(column.value)
      }
    })
  })

  connection.execSql(request)
}

// Nav to login pg by default
app.get('/', (_: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.sendFile('login.html', { root: viewsDir });
});
    

// **** Export default **** //

export default app;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "APTWebAPI",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx ts-node build.ts",
    "lint": "npx eslint --ext .ts src/",
    "lint:tests": "npx eslint --ext .ts spec/",
    "start": "node -r module-alias/register ./dist --env=production",
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "test": "nodemon --config ./spec/nodemon.json",
    "test:no-reloading": "npx ts-node --files -r tsconfig-paths/register ./spec"
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "watch": [
      "src"
    ],
    "ext": "ts, html",
    "ignore": [
      "src/public"
    ],
    "exec": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node --files -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src"
  },
  "_moduleAliases": {
    "@src": "dist"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "helmet": "^7.0.0",
    "inserturlparams": "^1.0.1",
    "jet-logger": "^1.3.1",
    "jet-validator": "^1.1.1",
    "jsonfile": "^6.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.1",
    "module-alias": "^2.2.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "tedious": "^16.4.0",
    "ts-command-line-args": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/find": "^0.2.1",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^11.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^4.3.5",
    "@types/jsonfile": "^6.1.1",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "@types/morgan": "^1.9.4",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.7",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.2.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.46.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "find": "^0.3.0",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0",
    "tedious": "^16.4.0", //I added this here
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try installing the types? Why _is_ that two lines? And why mix import and require?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry, I'm new to web dev and I figured I'd ask about my uncertainties here. How do I install types? I got the `tedious` code from this website, which said to use `tedious` to connect an express project to SQL Server: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#sql-server

Comment: @jonrsharpe I followed the instructions in that question and did `Restart TS server`, but nothing seems to have changed. The error is still there

Comment: Then [edit] the question, because right now the types are _not_ in your package file.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ah, I had the answers on a SO question sorted by recently modified. The highest scored answer in that question had the answer - `npm install @types/tedious`. Sorry about that. Thanks for your help!